# How to change colors on your status message using bootstrap and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap code that has div class alert, I want to find a way where the button is switched between on be changed its color to be green, if it switched off be red. I need some helpmates to this logic and my logic to this attempt is below, what the code does currently its not much other than the status color only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('locked_active')) {
      $('#switch_status').html('Switched off.');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=1LP18C8BQCYHYUI9&field8=0',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          format: 'text'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
          //$('#singlebtn').append(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=1LP18C8BQCYHYUI9&field8=1',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          format: 'text'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
          //$('#singlebtn').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="wrapper" align="center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger locked_active">OFF</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: You already have the answer in `alert-info` - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/  are you looking for `.removeClass` and `.addClass`? `.removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert-success")`?  (

Comment: @freedomn-m i only want to change the color, for each status when its clicked. If its on must be green and off must be red only.

Comment: right, so what happens if you replace `.alert-info` with `.alert-success` - does that not change the colour?

Comment: It does change the color to green

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: the switch between on and off is one, it must change. That is what i am aiming to achieve here. I hope make a sense here, please liaise with me.

Comment: Remove alert-info alert-success alert-danger, add alert-success (or alert-danger), ie: update your existing code to `$('#switch_status').html('Switched on.').removeClass("alert-info alert-success alert-danger").addClass("alert-success")`

Comment: Thanks mate managed to make it work, did both ways, one being success and one being off as red. Made my day mate, thanks.